# How to change Edittext color border in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a white theme in my application, but the borders of my
EditTexts are invisible. 
How can I change the color border of an EditText to black color for example ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You need to create a custom **drawable** and set as **background** to your edit text. For more details read [this](http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget) and [this](http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-9patch-files)